# imported packages in devtools

Tags: r, devtools

I develop my R package in RStudio. I use `load_all()` from devtools (either typing in the console or from the Build menu), which seems to work fine. If I then work on an R function in my package and source it, when I try and run the function I need to load the libraries it depends on, despite these other packages being imported (through the DESCRIPTION file).

So for example, I will get the message:

`could not find function "trellis.par.get"`

and I need to load the lattice package etc.

Is this expected behaviour? I would have thought devtools would have imported these other package dependencies, or am I misunderstanding something here?

Thanks

David

Comment: Do you have a `NAMESPACE` file?

Comment: Yes, and it contains import(lattice) - and all the other packages my package imports.